# GCP SQL proxy Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: The caller does not have permission

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, cloud-sql-proxy

I'm having a k8s deployment on GCP, and I'm connecting to the SQL database with SQL proxy. I'm deploying with a service account. I gave the service account owner permissions (it's just a test project), and CloudSQL client, CloudSQL instance user, CloudSQL admin.

The whole deployment goes all good, but it cannot connect to the proxy saying:

```
errors parsing config:
    Get "https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/org/instances/europe-west2~testProject/connectSettings?alt=json&prettyPrint=false": compute: Received 403 `Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: The caller does not have permission
This error could be caused by a missing IAM policy binding on the target IAM service account.
For more information, refer to the Workload Identity documentation:
    https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity#authenticating_to
```

And this is the manifest file (relevant parts of it):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  annotations:
    iam.gke.io/gcp-service-account: testProject@org.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  name: testProject
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: testProject
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testProject
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: testProject
  name: testProject
spec:
  progressDeadlineSeconds: 600
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 10
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testProject
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 2
      maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testProject
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: testProject
      containers:
        # app
        - name: cloud-sql-proxy
          command:
            - /cloud_sql_proxy
            - -enable_iam_login
            - -instances=org:europe-west2:testProject-db-staging=tcp:5432
            - -ip_address_types=PRIVATE,PUBLIC
            - -structured_logs
            - -term_timeout=5s
          image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.30.0
          # ...options
```

Why can't it connect to the database?

Comment: What's the permission of the testProject service account binding?

Comment: Did you complete step 3 to grant permission to use the service account: https://cloud.google.com/config-connector/docs/how-to/install-upgrade-uninstall#identity

Comment: Isn't the binding/mapping to k8s service account done automatically via the annotation?

Comment: @JohnHanley I did, but same error

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere
`
roles/cloudsql.admin
roles/cloudsql.client
roles/cloudsql.instanceUser
roles/owner
roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin`

Answer (score 0):

Use the answer described here:
[How to Connect to Cloud SQL Through Kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73504693/how-to-connect-to-cloud-sql-through-kubernetes)

The key is to the follow the tutorial very carefully. Few things to remember that I didn't realize I was missing:

1. `svc.id.goog` service account naming convention is very specific. Be sure you write it properly when adding it to the `workloadIdentityUser` group
2. make sure your service account is configured with the necessary roles (i.e. a member of the proper IAM roles). I think the key ones to make things work are `cloudsql`, `iam.ServiceAccount...`, and `iam.workloadIdentityUser` (e.g. `iam.serviceAccountClient` or other ones)
3. Make sure the k8 cluster worker pool is updated to use the Workload Identity you create, either by associating the pool during creation time, or by running `gcloud container node-pools update POOL_NAME`. If you didnt create a pool the POOL_NAME will be your default pool